# how to toggle between two list of arrays with one button react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

looking for advice on how to have one button that when clicked will switch the list of items to the alphabetized list of items and back when clicked again and so on. as of right now when i click the button it will show the alphabetized list but its just rendering on top of the original list already showing. not really sure on where to go from here

````
class MenuItems extends Component {

    state = {
        sortedItems: []
    }

    handleclick = (item) => {
        this.props.deleteMenuItem(item.id);
    }

    menuSort = () => {
         const ogList = [...this.props.menuItems]
        let sortedList = ogList.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        this.setState({sortedItems: sortedList})
    };

    render(){
        return ( 
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.menuSort}>filter a to z</button>

                {this.state.sortedItems.map((item) =>(
                    <li class="list" key={item.id}>
                        {item.name}
                        <br></br>
                        {item.body}
                        <br></br>
                        <img src={item.image}></img>
                        <br></br>
                        <button id={item.id} onClick={() => this.handleclick(item)}>delete </button>
                    </li>
                ))}

                
                {this.props.menuItems.map((item) =>(
                    <li class="list" key={item.id}>
                        {item.name}
                        <br></br>
                        {item.body}
                        <br></br>
                        <img src={item.image}></img>
                        <br></br>
                        <button id={item.id} onClick={() => this.handleclick(item)}>delete </button>
                    </li>
                ))}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, {deleteMenuItem})(MenuItems)```
````

Comment: What do you mean "back again"? How are the items initially sorted?

Comment: i would like the button when clicked will show only one list at a time when clicked so the page at first renders the props.menuItems map but when i click the button i want it to organize the list alphabetically by name

Comment: Yes, but then you want it to go back to the initial unsorted/sorted order when the button is clicked again. Shouldn't you be holding that initial data in state somewhere?

Comment: the initial data is comming in from the props.menuItems i thought

Comment: OK. But unless the parent passes in new data or you update the state of the component with changed data the component won't be rerendered. At some point that component has to be responsible for that data changing, whether it's managing that state, or calling a function in the parent to give it updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly thought to keep the sorted version in the state. But you have to somehow instruct the component to render the original list or the sorted one.

So you could add a flag in the `state` to specify which one you want.

You could also set the sorted list in the componentDidMount lifecycle event, and updated it whenever the `menuItems` change through the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle event.

So something like

```
  state = {
    sortedItems: [],
    showSorted: false
  };

  toggleSort = () => {
    this.setState(({ showSorted }) => ({
      showSorted: !showSorted
    }));
  };

  updateSortedItems() {
    const sorted = [...this.props.menuItems].sort((a, b) =>
      a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    );
    this.setState({
      sortedItems: sorted
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateSortedItems();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.menuItems !== prevProps.menuItems) {
      this.updateSortedItems();
    }
  }
```

and in your render method

```
let itemsToShow = this.props.menuItems;

if (this.state.showSorted) {
  itemsToShow = this.state.sortedItems;
}
```

and use the `itemsToShow` when you want to display them

```
{itemsToShow.map((item) => (
```

Full working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-heyrovsky-m3jvv